# How to solve class objecto has no atribute

Tags: python, class, attributes

beginner Python user here.
So, I´m trying to make a program that orders the files of my (many) Downloads folder.

I made a class object to work with the many folders:

```
class cContenedora:
def __int__(self, nCarp, dCarp): #nCarp Stands is the file name and dCarp Stands for file directory. 
    self.nCarp = nCarp
    self.dCarp = dCarp
```

So, y wrote a instance like this:

```
Download = cContenedora()
Download.nCarp = "Downloads/" 
#The side bar is for making a path to move my archives from with  shutil.move(path, dest)
Download.dCarp = "/Users/MyName/Download/" 
#This is for searching the folder with os.listdir(Something.dCarp)
```

Then, I wrote my function, and it goes something like this:

```
def ordenador(carpetaContenedora, formato, directorioFinal): #carpetaContenedora is a Download Folder
    
    carpetaContenedora = cContenedora() #carpetaContenedora one of the class objects
    dirCCont = os.listdir(carpetaContenedora.dCarp) #The to directory is carpetaContenedora.cCarp
    for a in dirCCont:
        if a.endswith(formato):
            path = "/Users/John Smith/" + carpetaContenedora().nCarp + a
            try:
                shutil.move(path, directorioFinal)
                print(Fore.GREEN + a + "fue movido exitosamente.")
            except:
                print(Fore.RED + "Error con el archivo" + a)
                pass
    
for trys in range(len(listaCarpetasDestino)-1): #Is a list full of directories.   
    for container in listaCarpetasFuente: #A short list of all my Downloads Folder.
        for formatx in listaFormatos: #listaFormatos is a list ful of format extensions like ".pdf"
            #try: #I disabled this to see the error istead of "Error Total"
                ordenador(container, formatx, listaCarpetasDestino[trys])
            #except:
                #print(Fore.RED + "Error Total") #I disabled this to see the error.
```

But every time I run it I get the following:

```
AttributeError: 'cContenedora' object has no attribute 'dCarp'
```

It says the error is in line 47 (the one with the os.listdir(carpetaContenedora.dCarp))

I´m sure is something small. Python is so amazing, but it also can be so frustrating not knowing what´s wrong.

Comment: There may be somthing wrong in this line Download.dCarp = "/Users/MyName/Download/"  recheck!

Answer (score 1):

There is a spelling mistake in the initialization of your instance. It should be "**init**" instead of "**int**".

In the class **cContenedora**, the function should be

```
class cContenedora:
       def __init__(self, nCarp, dCarp): 
           self.nCarp = nCarp
           self.dCarp = dCarp
```

Additionally, When you are passing in the parameter. Make sure to pass in both of the parameters in the line with Value.

`CContenedora(nCarp="something",dCarp="something")`

Answer (score -1):

Your class initializer, i.e., `__init__()` function has 2 parameters `nCarp` and `dCarp` but when you are actually creating the object there are no parameters passed.

Your function `ordenador` takes the first parameter as `carpetaContenedora`, on the first line same variable is assigned a new object of `cContenedora`, at this line the original values you passed are lost forever.

This could be the reason it is giving for the error.
Refer [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) for more details on how to create classes and instantiate the object.